# Listener for resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap collapsing menu and need to add css property to another div, when menu is collapsed. .nav-collapse inline height value changes, but the event listener doesnt work. So whats the problem? Or is there another way to make, what I want?

```
$('.nav-collapse').resize(function() {
            var height = $('.nav-collapse').height();
            $('.custom-class').css('margin-top', height);
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements don't have a `resize` event, just `window`.

You'll have to apply the `margin-top` another way, there just isn't an event to hook here. If the collapsing menu gets a class added to it or similar, you can probably use that if the other element is either a descendant or a sibling. (If it's neither, it gets really hard.)

Or you could hook the event(s) that close the collapsing menu, and handle the `margin-top` there (either immediately, or if the collapse is animated, after a delay).